# Invalid length returned for Javascript node list

Tags: javascript, webkit

I've tracked down a Javascript problem I've been having, the problem can be seen in this code, ran after page load:

```
var btns = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
console.log(btns);
divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
console.log(btns.length);
console.log(btns);
```

*When* this code works, (and doesn't show blank array []), it shows the array of buttons, then 0, then array of buttons, in the console. How can this be returning the wrong value for length??

Comment: Are any buttons added or removed shortly after this code is executed? `NodeList`s aren't snapshots; [they're "live" collections](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/NodeList#A_.22live.22_collection) that continue to change with the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like setting it as a DOMContentLoaded event fixed this.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {...}, false)
```

seems to be the correct event to set the onload code.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code:

```
<button>bt1</button><div>www</div>
<button>bt_2</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
var btns = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
console.log(btns);
divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
console.log(btns.length);
console.log(btns)
</script>
```

And it shows correctly:

```
[button, button]
2
[button, button]
```

Comment: Yes, and it does the same thing when I run in the inspector, but the page code works incorrectly. Could a global variable or something be messing it up?